# How do I find people around me who use ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I live in a medium-size city.

Is there a way for me to find other people in my area that use ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9078/how-do-i-find-people-around-me-who-use-ros?/) by [Alex Bravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27/alex-bravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 901 on 2011-02-15

Post score: 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We could always crowd-source the problem and have everyone add their location to one map.

[**Updated Location**](http://metrorobots.com/rosmap.html)

*edit: updated with data from the presentation slide, including Beta locations and other places with repositories*

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 17

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alex Bravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27/alex-bravo/) on 2011-02-16**:
Your crowd-sourcing solution sounds pretty good. It shouldn't be hard to do too considering location is one of the fields in profiles on this site.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-02-15**:
That's really cool David. I didn't know you could do collaborative stuff with Google Maps :)

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-06-05**:
I suggested Alex's idea in the feedback link here at answers.ros.org, but have no idea if anyone reads those suggestions. I think it would be really cool to map all of this info.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-06-05**:
People do read those :). I don't know if anyone actually acted on it, especially since not everyone actually fills in that field. If WG were to create a map, it would probably be better to geolocate all of the IPs that fetched from packages.ros.org (and get all that info for the mirrors as well).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A good start would be to check [ROS.org](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Repositories) and see if any of the Universities near you have a repository listed.

See page 19 of the PDF from the [ROS Introduction from the CoTeSys Fall School (PDF)](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Events/CoTeSys-ROS-School?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=ros_overview.pdf) for a map of many of the Repositories available.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since the map never got created, I had to deploy a little more radical solution - move to Silicon Valley. :)

---

Originally posted by [Alex Bravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27/alex-bravo/) with karma: 901 on 2012-06-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1